# "vector" tag needs to be split?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Currently, [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) seems to be used for 2 things:

- Data structures similar to C++'s `std::vector` (resizable arrays)
- Mathematical vectors (as used in e.g. computer graphics)

Should it be split?

Comment: Seems reasonable (as mathematical vectors are not resizable - they are more tuples with operations). But do you have any suggestions on how to name the resulting tags?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: maybe "c++-vector" or "stl-vector", vs. just "vector" for mathematical vectors?

Comment: Then you'd need a different one for the (Java) Vector, another for (Qt) QVector, ... not sure that's an improvement.